# maatwebsite download database

Tags: excel, laravel, export

i use laravel 8 and maatwebsite 3.1 , want to download (export) a table of my database as excel file by clicking an icon . as i searched , we must create a class by artisan `php artisan make:export blogExport --model=blog` and in controller use download method . `Excel::download(new blogExport, 'filename.xlsx');` . blogExport include collection() function that we should determine output matter in it .But I want write  function in controller and determine the output i want , directly in this function and not use blogExport . is it possible ? there is a method "CREATE" that can use but it is old and not supported by maatwebsite 3.1 . any reply is appreciated .

Comment: do you want create a custom query then give it to excell to download?

Comment: yes . i would like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class ExcellExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithEvents, WithStrictNullComparison,ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($header, $query)
    {
        $this->header = $header;
        $this->query = $query;
    }
    //======================================
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [$this->header];
    }
    //======================================
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->query);
        
    }
}
```

then pass your query like this:

```
$query = Estate::where($inputs)->with('landlord', 'rented', 'my_estate_list');
$headers=["code,type_caption,space,landlord,area,address,price"];
$resultExcell = new ExcellExport($headers, $query);
return Excel::download($resultExcell, 'file_name.xlsx');
```